# TradingView strategy API Address

Tags: pine-script

How do I pull a trading strategies buy and sell indicators into an API key to use on Binance for automatic buy and sell orders?

i can't find any reference on Pine Script

Answer (score 0):

You have to set an alert.
On the alert window you can set a webhook url (to your API), and you can set a message which will be sent in the json format to your webhook.
[image]
The pinescript code could look ike this :

```
if takeprofit > 0
    strategy.exit(id=textestop, from_entry="long", stop=stoploss, limit=takeprofit)
    // Mise en place du SL
    data := '{"client": "xxx", "apiKey": "yyy","secretKey": "zzz",
              "command": "linear_stop_limit_order",
              "side": "Sell",
               "qty": '+ str.tostring(Q_Jetons, "#.###") +',
               "limit": '+ str.tostring(stoploss,"#.#") +',
               "base_price": '+ str.tostring(close,"#.#") +'}'
    alert(data, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```